# How is fab.com double dotted line created : css or image?

Tags: php, html, css

Fab.com has great design with a double dotted line (both horizontal and vertical).

Above the word "Featured today", you can see one of those horizontal dotted double line.
With firebug, i can see it's located on .

How does fab.com manage to create this line: with css or image ? if css, with which attribute do you create such effect ?

Comment: 10 seconds with the firebug dom inspector will tell you what it is: an image background on the #fabWrapper container.

Comment: 5 seconds with the chrome developer tools, this can be a thing for a new "code" golf category :-)

Comment: 3 hours with IE should give you an idea..

Comment: -30 years with DeLorean.

Answer (score 2):

It's an image:

```
#fabWrapper {
    background: url("//dnok91peocsw3.cloudfront.net/relaunch/bg-mesh-2px-gap.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

The little dots fill up the whole wrapper element. Then the child elements on the page cover up everything but some small margins left between them, showing the dotted background.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect element it, you find it's an image set as background:
http://dnok91peocsw3.cloudfront.net/relaunch/bg-mesh-2px-gap.png

If you want to do that with CSS
You can use the "outline and border" and give them a dotted solid line. Or use two divs and give them border property.

`border:1px dotted #111;`

Answer (score 1):

You can make that using two `div` dotted line using `css`

Or you can use an `image` in the bg of a `div` and do a `repeat-y` in `css`

Answer (score 1):

they are setting their container to //dnok91peocsw3.cloudfront.net/relaunch/bg-mesh-2px-gap.png that repeats across the entire container width a padding of 2px. then each of the sections that they use, they set the background to white. if you start removing some of the sections or set one of their divs to a background:none, you can see the container.